# Java Vaadin: CSV to Grid

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I have a CSV File which I want to display in a Grid in Vaadin.
The File looks like this:

CTI.csv

```
Facebook
Twitter
Instagram
Wiki
```

So far i tried it with a while Loop and a for Loop. The for Loop looks like this:

```
Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File("C:/development/code/HelloWorld/src/CTI.csv"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
List<CTITools> tools = null;
for (Iterator<String> s = sc; s.hasNext(); ) {
    tools = Arrays.asList(new CTITools(s.next()));
}

Grid<CTITools> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.setItems(tools);
grid.addColumn(CTITools::getTool).setCaption("Tool");
layout.addComponents(grid);

setContent(layout);
```

The issue now is that it only shows the last entry "Wiki". If i hardcode the data like the following it works:

```
List<CTITools> tools;
tools = Arrays.asList(
            new CTITools("DFC"),
            new CTITools("AgentInfo"),
            new CTITools("Customer"));
            new CTITools("Wiki"));

Grid<CTITools> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.setItems(tools);
grid.addColumn(CTITools::getTool).setCaption("Tool");
```

So what am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the Loop work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `tools = Arrays.asList(new CTITools(s.next()));` creates new list on each iteration. If you want your items to be stored in one list you need to create it once. Then use `tools.add(new CTITools(s.next()))` to add the items to the same list in the loop.

Comment: Oh right, why didn't I realize that. So I have to create the Arrays before the Loop and then add the String inside, right?

Comment: Yes, just if you created a list of CTITools, you would add CTITools, not a String.

Comment: Right, makes sense. Thanks for your help and sorry to bother with such a basic problem!

Answer (score 1):

You create a new list at each iteration so you lose your previous content.

```
tools = Arrays.asList(new CTITools(s.next()));
```

You should only add items to the same `tools` list

```
List<CTITools> tools = new ArrayList<>();
for (Iterator<String> s = sc; s.hasNext(); ) {
    tools.add(new CTITools(s.next()));
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. @muzychuk already resolved the issues, I just have to wait a few minutes until I can accept his answer. Thank you anyways and for the code example!